# "large field of view" vs "high field of view"

Tags: differences, adjectives, comparisons

Which one is right between "**large** field of view" and "**high** field of view"?

Comment: Probably "wide field of view".  If the view is indeed wide.

Comment: @grizzly raises the point that there are two different meanings of "field of view".  One is simply the view that one can see, say, standing atop a mountain, while the other is a technical term used in computer gaming and related technologies.

Comment: I automatically assumed this was related to gaming since I enjoy playing games so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, **"wide field of view"** is the commonest collocation. **"Large field of view"** is also possible. "High field of view" is not even on the map:

[image]

According to the CORPUS OF CONTEMPORARY AMERICAN ENGLISH, **"wide field of view" is roughly five times more frequent than "large field of view"** (the screenshot list top adjectives preceding "field of view"):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Large field of view. 
Wider field of view.

High field of view I have never heard.

Here is a link which you use for more detail;

[Field of View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view_in_video_games)